# Cross platform desktop development

Tags: cross-platform, desktop-application, desktop

I would like to develop a cross platform (Linux/Windows) desktop service.
This service needs to run a local HTTP server and needs to have access to a local DB.
It doesn't have any GUI components though.

Also I need to be able to create an installer for both Linux and Windows.

What is the best language/framework/SDK to build such service ?

Java could be perfect for this but I'm not sure there is a decent installer builder out there.

10x
Gilad

Comment: Xojo lets you build standalone web apps that have a built-in HTTP server and can run as a service or daemon on Linux. http://developer.xojo.com/running-a-standalone-web-app-in-the-background

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered the Dlib C++ Library found at http://dlib.net/? It includes "A simple HTTP server object you can use to embed a web server into your applications."

As for an installer, perhaps you should consult the following resource: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_installation_software#Cross-platform.